# pyxb issues with assigning vlaues to anunbound inner complex element with known type

Tags: python, pyxb

I am trying to assign values to an unbound inner element of a predefined type but I am not able to validate it.
here is my example with reports.xsd  and the snippet of the code that is not working:
...

```
   <xs:element name="reports" type="tns:Reports"/>
<xs:complexType name="Reports">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="reportingGroups">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"
                        name="reportingGroup" type="tns:ReportingGroupType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ReportingGroupType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="description" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

---

```
import reports
rep=reports.reports()

rep.description="this report is ..." #works

rep.reportingGroups=pyxb.BIND()

rep.reportingGroups.append("ReportingGroupType(name='this title",id=xs.string("A1")) #works

print(rep.reportingGroups.toxml("utf-8"))  #does not work
```

I was not able to find a case similar to this one. I appreciate your help.
Malika

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you explained what "does not work" means to you.

This line:

```
rep.reportingGroups.append("ReportingGroupType(name='this title",id=xs.string("A1")) #works
```

is bizarre and does not work for me, producing an "invalid non-element content" error because the string `ReportingGroupType(name='this title`cannot be interpreted as an element of type `ReportingGroupType`.

If I replace that string with an object constructor and correct the name of the subordinate element it works:

```
rep.reportingGroups.append(reports.ReportingGroupType(title='not name', id='A1'))
```